# how to add rows dynamically in ruby on rails with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Application contains invoice line item. While creating new invoice, I need to add rows dynamically in table contains information regarding product name, description, and product unit cost.

I have a "Add" button, when user press this button one row will be added in the form.

Code from **new.html.erb** in which i have created table body.

```
 <tbody>
  <%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <tr id='row0'>
      <%= f.fields_for :products do | product | %>
        <td><%= product.input :product_name, placeholder: 'Product Name', label: false %></td>
        <td><%= product.input :product_description, placeholder: 'Product Description', label: false %></td>
        <td><%= product.input :product_price, placeholder: 'Product Unit Cost', label: false %></td>
        <% end %>     
        <td><button id="add_row" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='row1'></tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

now I need solution to add rows dynamically via jquery. So for that I tried following code.

but failed to generate output...**invoice_item.js** is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $("#add_row").click(function(){
    $('#row'+i).html("<td><%= product.input :product_name, placeholder: 'Product Name', label: false %></td><td><%= product.input :product_description, placeholder: 'Product Description', label: false %></td><td><%= product.input :product_price, placeholder: 'Product Unit Cost', label: false %></td>");
    $('#invoice_table').append('<tr id="row'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
    i++; 
    });
});
```

if I wanted to append the **new.html.erb** code to the page using jquery, what is the best way?

Comment: I think the best way would be https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_FNKR7jahM.

Comment: One thing what I noticed is you don't have any components with id `row`. You have `row0` and `row1`. Try changing `'#row'+i` to `'#row1'`

Comment: @Pavan- yes i used that '#row1'...but with this code it will add only one row..i need more rows....and another problem is after adding new row that  row is noot empty..it displays code i.e table data which is in ** .html()**.. i.e. <td><%= product.input :product_name, placeholder: 'Product Name', label: false %></td>